# INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR with rest api request in android paypal

Tags: android, api, rest, paypal, payment

I have implemented the rest api of payment with paypal in android application using this code 
:

```
   if (isset($_POST['paypal_response']) ) {

$json = json_decode( $_POST['paypal_response'], true );

    if (isset($json['proof_of_payment']['rest_api']) ) {

    echo 'rest api et voila le payment_id : '.$json['proof_of_payment']['rest_api']['payment_id'].'\n';

    $http_header_card = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization:Bearer ENxom5Fof1KqAffEsXtxwEDa6E1HTEK__KVdIsaCYF8C'
);



$ch = curl_init();

$get_request = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/{".$json['proof_of_payment']['rest_api']['payment_id']."}";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $get_request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_header_card );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$html = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $html;
```

I have also implemeted the verification of proof for adaptive payment (with paypal account)

but this one above, always send me this response :

```
{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR"}1
```

I don't know the reason knowing that I have followed the official documentation [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/)

here is the code of the doc which I have converted to php :

```
    curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI \
 -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 -H "Authorization:Bearer ENxom5Fof1KqAffEsXtxwEDa6E1HTEK__KVdIsaCYF8C"
```

how can I fix this issue

thanks